# Controlling USB keyboard and mouse

Tags: usb, driver, hid

We have a hardware device, with an LCD display. It supports an USB interface to connect keyboard and mose. Using these keyboard and mouse, we can navigate to varios menu items and edit entries.

We have couple of test cases written to verify that mouse click and keyboard input events are working when pressed respective key.

My task is to automate these test cases.

I donot have any control to the hardware device, as I can not access the o/s kernel or any application running there. There is one way to verify what is currently displayed on the UI. So I have to use that and verify whether the mouse/keyboard has performed the appropriate events.

As I have gone through couple of previous posts, it seems like that one of the way to achieve this is through virual HID device driver rather than actual keyboard and mosue. But I am not sure how to achieve it.

Please do help me for it. I am fine with any programming language.

I am more interested to simulate the mouse and keyboard events.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to write your own driver.  AutoHotKey does pretty much anything you can think of, and the scripting language is quite easy to learn.

You can get it here:

http://www.autohotkey.com/

Since you're using linux, here's a similar project that will run on linux:

http://sikuli.org/

Comment: This is not I am looking for. This is a network device and not my PC.

Comment: @rpg: In that case, what OS does it (the network device) run? A virtual driver would be very different across different OSes.